# Button ID's inside OnPostExecute

Tags: java, android, if-statement, button, view

I am trying to use else if statement inside OnPostExecute so when a button is clicked API with data is downloaded, a correct title (in this case Honda or Suzuki) fetched from String source file, both of them are put in a bundle and transferred to another activity. Then the title is used as the title on my DisplayDataActivity and data is put into TextView.
So I use the same activity to display my data, just with different titles and data. 
There are 20 buttons in total but once I know how to get id's for two of them I will extend it to the rest of them. 
However I cannot pass my button IDs inside OnPostExecute (so I can select the correct else_if statement based on the button id clicked). 
Is there any way to do that? 
I would be super grateful for any help!

!UPDATED CODE:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public class Wrap
{
    public String dataPassedInOnClick;
    public String resultData;
}

public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Wrap> {
    private Context mContext;
    private View rootView;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONTask(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public JSONTask(Context context, View rootView){
        this.mContext=context;
        this.rootView=rootView;
    }

    @Override
    protected Wrap doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            Wrap wrapper=new Wrap();
            wrapper.dataPassedInOnClick=params[0];
            wrapper.resultData=buffer.toString();

            return wrapper;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading data...");
        pDialog.show();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Wrap wrapResult) {
        super.onPostExecute(wrapResult);
        this.pDialog.dismiss();

        if (wrapResult.dataPassedInOnClick.contains("api_suzuki")) {
            String activity_title =
                    getResources().getString(R.string.suzuki);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    DisplayDataActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("title", activity_title);
            extras.putString("JSON_Object", wrapResult.resultData);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (wrapResult.dataPassedInOnClick.contains("api_honda")) {
            String activity_title =
                    getResources().getString(R.string.honda);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    DisplayDataActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("title", activity_title);
            extras.putString("JSON_Object", wrapResult.resultData);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (wrapResult.dataPassedInOnClick.contains("api_kawasaki")) {
            String activity_title =
                    getResources().getString(R.string.kawasaki);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    DisplayDataActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("title", activity_title);
            extras.putString("JSON_Object", wrapResult.resultData);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (wrapResult.dataPassedInOnClick.contains("api_triumph")) {
            String activity_title =
                    getResources().getString(R.string.triumph);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    DisplayDataActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("title", activity_title);
            extras.putString("JSON_Object", wrapResult.resultData);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (wrapResult.dataPassedInOnClick.contains("api_bmw")) {
            String activity_title =
                    getResources().getString(R.string.bmw);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    DisplayDataActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("title", activity_title);
            extras.putString("JSON_Object", wrapResult.resultData);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (wrapResult.dataPassedInOnClick.contains("api_hyousung")) {
            String activity_title =
                    getResources().getString(R.string.hyousung);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    DisplayDataActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("title", activity_title);
            extras.putString("JSON_Object", wrapResult.resultData);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (wrapResult.dataPassedInOnClick.contains("api_ducati")) {
            String activity_title =
                    getResources().getString(R.string.ducati);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    DisplayDataActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("title", activity_title);
            extras.putString("JSON_Object", wrapResult.resultData);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (wrapResult.dataPassedInOnClick.contains("api_harley")) {
            String activity_title =
                    getResources().getString(R.string.harley);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    DisplayDataActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("title", activity_title);
            extras.putString("JSON_Object", wrapResult.resultData);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (wrapResult.dataPassedInOnClick.contains("api_aprilia")) {
            String activity_title =
                    getResources().getString(R.string.aprilia);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    DisplayDataActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("title", activity_title);
            extras.putString("JSON_Object", wrapResult.resultData);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (wrapResult.dataPassedInOnClick.contains("api_ktm")) {
            String activity_title =
                    getResources().getString(R.string.ktm);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    DisplayDataActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("title", activity_title);
            extras.putString("JSON_Object", wrapResult.resultData);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (wrapResult.dataPassedInOnClick.contains("api_mv")) {
            String activity_title =
                    getResources().getString(R.string.mv);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    DisplayDataActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("title", activity_title);
            extras.putString("JSON_Object", wrapResult.resultData);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (wrapResult.dataPassedInOnClick.contains("api_bajaj")) {
            String activity_title =
                    getResources().getString(R.string.bajaj);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    DisplayDataActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("title", activity_title);
            extras.putString("JSON_Object", wrapResult.resultData);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (wrapResult.dataPassedInOnClick.contains("royal")) {
            String activity_title =
                    getResources().getString(R.string.royal);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    DisplayDataActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("title", activity_title);
            extras.putString("JSON_Object", wrapResult.resultData);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (wrapResult.dataPassedInOnClick.contains("api_hero")) {
            String activity_title =
                    getResources().getString(R.string.hero);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    DisplayDataActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("title", activity_title);
            extras.putString("JSON_Object", wrapResult.resultData);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (wrapResult.dataPassedInOnClick.contains("api_indian")) {
            String activity_title =
                    getResources().getString(R.string.indian);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    DisplayDataActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("title", activity_title);
            extras.putString("JSON_Object", wrapResult.resultData);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
public void onSuzuki(View view) {
    JSONTask objJSONTask=new JSONTask(MainActivity.this);
    objJSONTask.execute("api_suzuki");
}
public void onHonda(View view) {
    JSONTask objJSONTask=new JSONTask(MainActivity.this);
    objJSONTask.execute("api_honda");
}

public void onKawasaki(View view) {
    JSONTask objJSONTask=new JSONTask(MainActivity.this);
    objJSONTask.execute("api_kawasaki");
}
public void onTriumph(View view) {
    JSONTask objJSONTask=new JSONTask(MainActivity.this);
    objJSONTask.execute("api_triumph");
}

public void onBmw(View view) {
    JSONTask objJSONTask=new JSONTask(MainActivity.this);
    objJSONTask.execute("api_bmw");
}
public void onHyuosung(View view) {
    JSONTask objJSONTask=new JSONTask(MainActivity.this);
    objJSONTask.execute("api_hyuosung");
}
public void onDucati(View view) {
    JSONTask objJSONTask=new JSONTask(MainActivity.this);
    objJSONTask.execute("api_ducati");
}
public void onHarley(View view) {
    JSONTask objJSONTask=new JSONTask(MainActivity.this);
    objJSONTask.execute("api_harley");
}
public void onAprilia(View view) {
    JSONTask objJSONTask=new JSONTask(MainActivity.this);
    objJSONTask.execute("api_aprilia");
}
public void onKtm(View view) {
    JSONTask objJSONTask=new JSONTask(MainActivity.this);
    objJSONTask.execute("api_ktm");
}
public void onMv(View view) {
    JSONTask objJSONTask=new JSONTask(MainActivity.this);
    objJSONTask.execute("api_mv");
}
public void onBajaj(View view) {
    JSONTask objJSONTask=new JSONTask(MainActivity.this);
    objJSONTask.execute("api_bajaj");
}
public void onRoyal(View view) {
    JSONTask objJSONTask=new JSONTask(MainActivity.this);
    objJSONTask.execute("api_royal");
}
public void onHero(View view) {
    JSONTask objJSONTask=new JSONTask(MainActivity.this);
    objJSONTask.execute("api_hero");
}
public void onIndian(View view) {
    JSONTask objJSONTask=new JSONTask(MainActivity.this);
    objJSONTask.execute("api_indian");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing and getting the rootView for every case in your onPostExecute, when your are trying to get the id by calling `int id = view.getId ();` you are actually getting the id of the rootView every time, so you have to pass the view of every button or figure out another way to do it.

What you can do in this case is compare the string that you are passing in the `onClick` method, since you already are passing a different string for every case, you already knows from where is called your `JSONTask` method, so you don't need the view of the button pressed because it would be redundant.

Try this:

```
public class Wrap
{
    public String dataPassedInOnClick;
    public String resultData;
}

public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Wrap> {
    private Context mContext;
    private View rootView;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONTask(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public JSONTask(Context context, View rootView){
        this.mContext=context;
        this.rootView=rootView;
    }

    @Override
    protected Wrap doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            Wrap wrapper=new Wrap();
            wrapper.dataPassedInOnClick=params[0];
            wrapper.resultData=buffer.toString();

            return wrapper;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading data...");
        pDialog.show();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Wrap wrapResult) {
        super.onPostExecute(wrapResult);
        this.pDialog.dismiss();

        if (wrapResult.dataPassedInOnClick.contains("Honda") ||
                wrapResult.dataPassedInOnClick.contains("honda")) {
            String activity_title =
                    getResources().getString(R.string.Honda);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    DisplayDataActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("title", activity_title);
            extras.putString("JSON_Object", wrapResult.resultData);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (wrapResult.dataPassedInOnClick.contains("Suzuki") ||
                wrapResult.dataPassedInOnClick.contains("suzuki")) {
            String activity_title =
                    getResources().getString(R.string.Suzuki);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    DisplayDataActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("title", activity_title);
            extras.putString("JSON_Object", wrapResult.resultData);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

We have to define a class Wrap because the `doInBackground` method only can return a single object.

Comment: Hi! My buttons execute API's, in OnPostExecute I want to have an else_if statement that would be picking correct title from String source file based on the ID of button pressed (so Honda or Suzuki) then it's put in a bundle and transferred into another activity.  So my buttons work fine, its the issue with transferring button's ID into OnPostExecuted. :)

Comment: which view are you passing in the OnPostExecute?

Comment: That's the question I am asking. How can I access the button IDs inside OnPostExecute.

Comment: Post more code please, I have an idea of what could be but I need to se how are you using your method, update your question and I'll update my answer

Comment: thanks for your answer! I have put my Main Activity code in the question above. Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know if it works for you

Comment: hi there! Thank you for your help! It works quite nicely however I came across a problem that when I expand your code to all of my 14 buttons (so 14 else-if  statements in OnPostExecute) it only "sees" the first 10 of them. After debugging the code and testing it in various configurations I confirm that the first 10 work and then all additional ones are not seen. Do you know what could be the reason behind it?

Comment: these 4 statements that are not working, compares always the same?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply! So no matter what 4 buttons I remove (so first, last or from the middle), always remaining 10 works. I have updated my code above, I would be extremely grateful if you maybe could have a look and see if you can spot the mistake. Thank you very much friend!

Comment: A very weird thing happened, I moved the else-if statement for my second button all the way to the bottom of the statements and it fixed the problem. 
I have no idea how it changes the code but with the second else-if statement right at the bottom seems to work. Nevertheless thank you very much for your help friend!! :)